# mongodb query to verify embedded array sequence numbers

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

given a document structure as shown, where the trades array can have thousands of items... how on earth could one do a query that would verify that the sequence always has 'startTradeId' one number higher than the previous items 'endTradeId', all the way through the array? is this even possible?

```js
    {
      "name": "STOCK",
      "trades": [{
          "endTradeId": 41306,
          "startTradeId": 41302,
          ...
        },
        {
          "endTradeId": 41301,
          "startTradeId": 41297,
          ...
        },
        {
          "endTradeId": 41296,
          "startTradeId": 41240,
          ...
        },
        ...
      ]
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use $where operator like below :

```
db.your_collection.find( { $where : function(){ return "this.trades.startTradeId > this.trades.endTradeId" }});
```

Comment: What I need to do is not verify the sequence in one doc.. I need to verify that that for example: trades[0].startTradeId == trades[1].endTradeId+1, all the way through the array of trades.

Is this even possible with a mongo query?